# How to compare array to string and increment variable per result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following Javascript code:

```
  var test = ['hello', 'my', 'name'];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (test === "name") {
      //In the array!
      ct = "found";
    } else {
      ct = "not found";
    }
  };
```

Here I am trying to loop through the amount of arrays in `data`, let's say 100 results, and then determine whether `var test` contains the array string of 'name'.

I have ran this and printed out the result of `ct` in the console log and everytime it prints out `ct` as 'not found'.

The point of this is to find how many strings of whatever I define `test` there are in an array.

Comment: Hint: you don't use the `i` variable anywhere.

Comment: Hint: use indexOf() rather than comparing the array and string

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What is your `data` variable. You are looping through it, but the code executed inside the for loop is not related to `data`.  
`test` cannot be equals to `"name"` because `test` is an array.

Comment: `ct` could be toggled between `"found"` and `"not found"` if loop does not `break`

Comment: @zoom how do I compare a string to an array? `data` contains a value of 100

Comment: You do not compare a string to an array, but as @JosephYoung pointed out, you can use the `indexOf` method on array to find if it contains a given value (a specific string in your case).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to find if item exists then you can use

```
var test = ["hello","my","name"];
var element = "hello";
var index = test.indexOf(element);
if(index != -1){
     //it exists 
     console.log(element + " exists at index " + index);
}else{
    //it doesn't
    console.log(element + " doesn't exist in array");
}
```

If you rather want to loop through array like  you began:

```
  var test = ['hello', 'my', 'name'];
  var name = "hello";
  var ct = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (test[i] === name ) {
      //In the array!
      ct = "found";
      break; // if next element is not name, so if you found break
    } else {
      ct = "not found";
    }
  };
  console.log(ct);
```